# Button looks awful in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

Hello I am making a button to work in outlook 2010 and the problem is that the button image wont centre vetically and the padding & margin wont display. Is there anyone who can help me solve this issue? Works fine on most email clients.

```
<table style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:center; padding:0; float:left; " align="center" >
<tbody >
<tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left" >

<td style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; vertical-align:top; display:block; color:#fff; font-family:'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight:normal; line-height:19px; font-size:16px; text-align:left; background-color:#EB7201; width:auto !important; " valign="top" align="center" >

<div class="mktEditable" id="cta-btn">

<a href="#pramrylink" style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;letter-spacing:1px;vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; margin: 10px;padding: 10px;">
<span style="vertical-align:middle; margin-left:5px;">Primary Button</span>
<img src="http://eu-lon03.marketo.com/rs/brotheruk/images/arrow-orange.png" alt="facebook" border="0" width="30" height="20" style="vertical-align: middle;">
<br>
</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Margin and padding should really be replaced with td's to keep the email format consistent across all clients. But for you code above removing the text-align: left; on the tr should fix it.

YOU SHOULD READ THIS ON ALLOWED USE OF CSS IN EMAILS https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

I've removed stuff and added it below for you to work from.

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" >
<tbody >
<tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left;" align="left" >

<td style="color:#fff; font-family:'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight:normal; line-height:19px; font-size:16px;  " valign="middle" align="center" >

<div class="mktEditable" id="cta-btn">

<a href="#pramrylink" style="width: 180px; 
    color: #fff; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 10px;
    background-color:#EB7201; ">
<span style="vertical-align:middle;" align="left">Primary Button</span>
<img src="http://eu-lon03.marketo.com/rs/brotheruk/images/arrow-orange.png" alt="facebook" border="0" width="30" height="20" style="vertical-align: middle;">
<br>
</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

- Floats are replaced with `align: left/right;`
- Margins should be replaced with more complex combinations of tr's and td's, if something need to be centred like an image then `align:center;` on the wrapping `td` should do that.

Comment: <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#EB7035" style="padding: 12px 18px 12px 18px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px" align="center"><a href="http://litmus.com" target="_blank" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">I am a button &rarr;</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table> Would this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try reset everything on the link (0 line-height, 0 padding, 0 font-size) and apply the styles (fix line-height, fix padding, and fix font-size) inside the link into a span where you apply the resetted styles.

I suggest to try a lot different css implementations and resend your mails.

Tip: Campaignmonitor offers a good list according to CSS and Newsletters
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/